# Use of commas before "that"

Tags: commas

I am not sure if and in which cases I have to use a comma before *"that"*. Consider the following examples:

> The first point is, *that* [...]
>
> One major problem about financial returns is, *that* they are [...]
>
> In [...] one can see, *that* both tails are heavier.
>
> The model implies, *that* the returns insist of a [...]

I am not sure about the commas in this context.

Comment: This has little to do with your question, but, whenever I see myself using the verb _is_ that way in writing, I try to restructure the sentence. So, instead of: _One major problem about financial returns is that they are X_, I might write: _X is a major problem with financial returns_. Also, instead of: _The first point is that both tails are heavier,_ it would get shortened to: _First, both tails are heavier_. Sentences usually read much better after such editing.

Answer (score 6):

None of the examples you gave require a comma. As a rule of thumb, you don't use a comma before a clause that begins with *that*.

You're veering to the territory of restrictive and nonrestrictive clauses. A restrictive clause limits the meaning of a sentence when you remove it. A nonrestrictive clause doesn't. Here are two examples (forgive the passive voice):

Restrictive:
The rules of grammar that are obsolete should be ignored. 
Just the crusty old ones that I don't agree with.

Nonrestrictive:
The rules of grammar, which are obsolete, should be ignored. 
Yes, all of them!

As you can see, they are *very* different sentences.

Comment: I think that, that being the case, we should tread warily.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would remove all of them.

In general, *that* is not introduced by a comma, as this would separate the two sentences which *that* (conjunction) links.

Besides, when you use *that* as a relative pronoun, you cannot use it in non defining sentences (where you use *which*), but these are the only ones where a comma is needed, to separate them from the main clause.

Summing up, all the sentences you have provided can do without commas before *"that"*.