# Do I put commas in that's phrases?

Tags: relative-clauses, commas

Should I put any commas here?

> Paint the fence that's red green.

(meaning "Paint the red fence with green paint.")

> Move the wheelbarrow that's on the stairs below the stairs.

(Could be shortened to "Move the wheelbarrow on the stairs below the stairs."

Comment: Unless you want to confuse your listener/reader, you should rewrite the sentences to make your meaning clear. **Paint the red fence green** is so much easier to follow.

Comment: @Ronald. True but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: The canonical may be *[Use of commas before "that"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/)*.

Answer (score 1):

'That' is used with what are called restrictive clauses, meaning 'that's red' is necessary to identify *which* fence. Commas are not used to set off these clauses.

Use who or which with non-restrictive clauses, where the info in the clause is NOT needed to identify which person or thing you're talking about. In this example you know which fence without the clause.

> paint John's fence, which is now red, green.